# Bootstrap Drop-Down li Customization Not Working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to customize the Bootstrap Drop-Down list as below by overwritting the li class but it is nit working! There is an example [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/AXwga/1/) as well

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
 <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
 <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
 <li class="divider"></li>
 <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
</ul>
```

and CSS is like

```
.dropdown-menu li: hover {
   background-color:#CCC;
  }
```

Is there any way I can add more spacing between li(s) as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) and the fact that the background-color that appears on `:hover` is actually a linear-gradient. To change this, you'll just want to use more specific selector:

```
.container .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
background-color: peru;
background-image: none; /* to disable the gradient */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AXwga/5/

Answer (score 0):

You want to edit this entry in the bootstrap.css file to change the defaults color and vertical padding:

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
    clear: both;
    color: #333333;
    display: block;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 3px 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

There is also a matching hover you should change.

EDIT: In the Bootstrap file, look for this:

```
.dropdown-menu li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu li > a:focus,
.dropdown-submenu:hover > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #0081c2;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#0088cc), to(#0077b3));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff0088cc', endColorstr='#ff0077b3', GradientType=0);
}
```

Comment: Hi Femi thanks for your comment I update the code but this is not changing anything on hover I also add :hover filter after li >a but not working!

Answer (score 0):

```
.dropdown-menu li{
   padding: 5px 0;
}
or
.dropdown-menu li{
   line-height:25px;
}
```